# Can I create a Smart Folder for vertical videos?

Tags: finder, spotlight, smart-folders

I want to create a Smart Folder in Finder that shows videos with height >= width. Is that possible? The UI for a comparison lets me compare width with a number like 3800, not with height:

[image]

Comment: You *might* be able to do this in Raw Query, but it's not something i'm practised in - This has a basic guide - https://www.macworld.com/article/231132/macos-how-to-use-spotlights-query-language-to-create-an-all-my-files-like-feature.html & this contains what appears to be the full syntax - https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/documentation/Carbon/Conceptual/SpotlightQuery/Concepts/QueryFormat.html - showing < & > are valid comparisons, but I can't find anything that states you can compare metadata attributes directly.

Comment: Full list of attributes - https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/documentation/CoreServices/Reference/MetadataAttributesRef/Reference/CommonAttrs.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40001694-SW1

Comment: @Tetsujin Thanks. The pixel width attribute doesn't seem to work even when comparing against a constant. Whether I select Pixel width = 800 or 8000 I get the same videos. Does it work for you?

Comment: pixel width = 4000 works for the one photo in my test folder shot portrait. idk if this works for video, I don't really have anything to test on, I'm a photographer. Try >=  or <= rather than specific sizes. I'm really not very good at using this as a language, sorry. The test would be to see if width > height works. The syntax guides don't show a way to compare variables directly.

Comment: No, it is not possible to create what you want as a Smart Folder. Searches of the Spotlight index do not allow comparison of fields. But there are multi-step ways getting the what you want. For example using 2 apps: Search for all videos using HoudahSpot, including width and height in results, saving the results to a CSV, opening the CSV in Numbers and add a column comparing height and width.

Comment: @Gilby Thanks, it looks like you're right: a raw query of kMDItemPixelWidth <= kMDItemPixelHeight doesn't work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Spotlight (in Finder or other app) does not allow comparison of metadata. So what you want can't be done in Finder.

But as a one-line Workaround:

Download and install [ExifTool](https://exiftool.org).

At the command line (e.g. using Terminal)

```
exiftool -csv -ext mp4 -ext mov -R -SourceImageWidth -SourceImageHeight <directory> -if '$SourceImageWidth < $sourceImageHeight'
```

Replace <directory> by a top level directory or volume containing your videos.  As an example (I mostly do photos):

```
exiftool -csv -ext mp4 -ext mov -R -SourceImageWidth -SourceImageHeight /Volumes/Photos -if '$SourceImageWidth < $sourceImageHeight'
SourceFile,SourceImageWidth,SourceImageHeight
/Volumes/Photos/Photos.photoslibrary/originals/B/B01CABBB-A3D8-4A00-9A01-F59755E4B03E.mp4,888,1920
/Volumes/Photos/PhotoSync/After LR Import/RPReplay_Final1638485087.mp4,888,1920
/Volumes/Photos/LightroomMasters/Apple/2021/2021-12-02/20211202-RPReplay_Final1638485087.mp4,888,1920
/Volumes/Photos/LightroomJPEG/Apple/2021/2021-12-02/20211202-RPReplay_Final1638485087.mp4,888,1920
 8965 directories scanned
 1317 files failed condition
    4 image files read
```

In the command:

- -csv: output as comma separated
- -ext: find files with these extensions
- -R: recurse all directories
- -SourceImageWidth and -SourceImageHeight: fields to include in output
- -if: selection criterion

Depending on the file type, you may need to replace SourceImageWidth with ImageWidth, etc.